# Error in updating multiple MySQL tables in one update statement

Tags: php, mysql

**Hi,**

I am having

> Query was empty

error, when updating data.

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1"))
{
   $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE client,release SET client.`client_name`=%s, release.`client_name`=%s WHERE client.`client_id`=%s AND release.`client_id`=%s", GetSQLValueString($_POST['newcust'], "text"), GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "int"));
   mysql_select_db($database_trackntrace, $trackntrace);
   $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $trackntrace) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I think there is a problem with the query, can any one please identify where's the problem.

**Kind Regards**

Comment: What does `var_dump($updateSQL);` output? It's probably not what you think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the sprintf function.
You tell sprintf you are going to pass 4 strings to it, but you only pass 2.

Because you only pass 2 parameters, and it requires 4, it will return false.

Try adding this above your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

This is the error you should get with the above settings:

```
Warning: sprintf() [<a href='function.sprintf'>function.sprintf</a>]: Too few arguments
```

What you want to change it to to fix this problem:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1"))
{
   $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE client,release SET client.`client_name`=%s, release.`client_name`=%s WHERE client.`client_id`=%s AND release.`client_id`=%s", GetSQLValueString($_POST['newcust'], "text"), GetSQLValueString($_POST['newcust'], "text"), GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "int"), GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "int"));
   mysql_select_db($database_trackntrace, $trackntrace);
   $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $trackntrace) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I've corrected it, but its still not updating column in both tables.
` $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE `client`,`release` SET `client`.`client_name`=%s, `release`.`client_name`=%s WHERE `release`.`client_name`=%s AND `client`.`client_id`=%s", GetSQLValueString($_POST['newcust'], "text"), GetSQLValueString($_POST['newcust'], "text"), GetSQLValueString($_POST['newcust'], "text"),GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "int"));`

Answer (score 2):

Release is a reserved word ,use backticks.

```
UPDATE client,`release` SET client.`client_name`=%s, `release`.`client_name`=%s 
WHERE client.`client_id`=%s AND `release`.`client_id`=%s",     GetSQLValueString($_POST['newcust'], "text"), GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "int"));
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

Comment: Use backticks on column names also.

Comment: This is a valid suggestion but doesn't address the original question that was asked.